# Failed to start Hadoop namenode in cloudera CDH5 on debian OS

Tags: hadoop, cloudera-cdh

I am installing Cloudera on debian OS.

this is my core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://hadoop-test-1:8020</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>io.compression.codecs</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DefaultCodec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BZip2Codec,com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec,com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzopCodec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>fs.trash.interval</name>
        <value>0</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>fs.trash.checkpoint.interval</name>
        <value>0</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>hadoop.proxyuser.mapred.groups</name>
        <value>*</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>hadoop.proxyuser.mapred.hosts</name>
        <value>*</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

when i try to start the name node I am getting the following errors.

```
# sudo service hadoop-hdfs-namenode start
```

these are the errors that i have received when i execute the above cmd

1. FAIL - Failed to start Hadoop namenode. Return value: 1 ... failed!
2. in hadoop-hdfs-namenode-hadoop-test-1.log file : 
   Invalid URI for NameNode address (check fs.defaultFS): file:/// has no authority.

Comment: Shouldnt cloudera manager be setting these xml values for you?

Comment: @cricket_007 I believe the OP is using the Cloudera Tarballs.

Comment: @franklinsijo I think manager is available as a tarball

Comment: Anyway, `check fs.defaultFS): file:/// has no authority`, so obviously the wrong files are being edited / shown here